# Do I really need ng-cloak to "protect" ng-include content at launch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-directive

I well know that when the page is loaded, Angular may not be fully load, that's why some `ng-bind` and `ng-cloak` are useful.
However, I've just noticed that the content of the `ng-include` is parsed BEFORE angular is loaded, leading to some ugly display of not evaluated `{{myVar}}` for some milliseconds/seconds. 
How could the `ng-include` directive (owned by Angular) be parsed if angular is not fully loaded?
**Do I need to transform the following code:**

```
<body id="home" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    <div ng-include src="'/app/topnav/top-nav.tpl.html'"></div>
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

(the issue here is that `top-nav.tpl.html` is parsed before Angular is fully loaded)

**to:**

```
<body id="home" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
    <div ng-cloak>
      <div ng-include src="'/app/topnav/top-nav.tpl.html'"></div>
      <div>
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Angular *is* loaded if `ng-include` is being run. If bindings in your template are being shown in plain text, then the template has not been compiled yet. Angular is loaded, but it does things in steps.

Comment: Yes, that what I eventually thought.. :)  Thanks :)

Comment: If you want, you can write your comment as the answer, so that I validate it. I'm sure that a lot of people would ask the same.